# Items being displayed when query is empty in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-next

I am learning react, and I have made a sample tv show app using an example off freecodecamp. It is all working okay from what I can see however after searching for something and then backspacing everything in the search box, it shows results when it shouldn't be, can anyone see a mistake I have made in my code?

```
class SeriesList extends React.Component {
  state = {
    series: [],
    query: ''
  }

  onChange = async e => {
    this.setState({query: e.target.value});
    const response = await fetch(
      `https://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=${this.state.query}`
    );
    const data = await response.json();
    this.setState({series: data});
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" onChange={this.onChange} value={this.state.query} />
        <ul>
          <SeriesListItem list={this.state.series} />
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I have it on codepen here.

https://codepen.io/crash1989/pen/ERxPGO

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One else point you can use await for setState

```
onChange = async e => {    
    await this.setState({query: e.target.value});
    const response = await fetch(
      `https://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=${this.state.query}`
    );
    const data = await response.json();
    this.setState({series: data});
  }
```

Your request will be performed after changing query

Comment: @ArneHugo I checked the API and it returns empty result if query is empty. Problem was in the query which stayed not empty after deleting from input because of async

Comment: You're right @Sabik, I must have been a bit quick to judge. I'll delete my comment.

Comment: Quick question by the way: What happens if the first of two successive network calls returns last? Will you not still see the result for the wrong query?

Comment: @ArneHugo theoretically it is possible but obviously this means problem on backend when backend can't process requests step by step and skips some requests

Comment: packets traveling across the internet may very well arrive in a different order than they were sent out, so regardless of what assumptions you make about the backend, the last response received is not necessarily that of the last request made. Though your solution will appear to work when tested, it is not safe from this effect, which will cause sporadic, buggy behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

`setState` works async. So there is no guarantee, that `this.state.query` has been updated after calling `this.setState({query: e.target.value})`. So your url contains the previous state eventually.

There are two options:

1. Use the event data for the new query:

   ```
   const response = await fetch(
      `https://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=${e.target.value}`
   );
   ...
   ```
2. Use the setState callback second arg

   ```
   this.setState({query: e.target.value}, () => {
     const response = await fetch(
       `https://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=${this.state.query}`
     );
     ...
   })
   ```

This is a good article about the async nature of `setState` https://medium.com/@wereHamster/beware-react-setstate-is-asynchronous-ce87ef1a9cf3.

Answer (score 0):

#### Problem

There are race conditions: When you type two+ letters you make two+ network calls. The first network call may be last to complete, and then you show results for the wrong query.

I fixed it in this pen: https://codepen.io/arnemahl/pen/zaYNxv

#### Solution

Keep track of results for all queries you have ever gotten the response to. Always how the data returned for the current query. (Also, don't make multiple API calls for the same query, we already know).

```js
state: {
  seriesPerQuery: {}, // Now a map with one result for each query you look up
  query: [],
}

...

onChange = async e => {
  ...

  // Now keep the results of the old querys, in addition to the new one
  // whenever you get an API response
  this.setState(state => ({
    seriesPerQuery: {
      ...state.seriesPerQuery,
      [query]: data,
    }
  }));
}
```